# Acessiblidade Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, acessibilidade

Olá estou desenvolvendo um projeto e implementando acessibilidade nele. Até ai tudo bem, o leitor de tela funciona tá tudo ok.

Meu problema é quando eu saio da tela A e vou para a tela B, na tela B tem um loading, eu gostaria de avisar ao leitor de tela que um carregamento está sendo executado.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: coloca um som ^^

Comment: Carrgando nova pagina.. acessibilidade custa caro..

Comment: Eu sei hehehe e o cliente também! Não gostaria de usar som, o próprio leitor de tela já está lendo ela. O projeto já está 95% acessível, gostaria de alguma definição do WAI-ARIA da W3C para isso, mas não encontrei nada.

Comment: Acho que estes artigos podem ajudá-lo: [How to create a simple CSS loading spinner & make it accessible](https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-a-simple-css-loading-spinner-make-it-accessible-e5c83c2e464c) e ["It’s Alive!": Apps That Feed Back Accessibly](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/04/its-alive-apps-that-feed-back-accessibly/)

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei pessoal, o Valdeir Psr me deu uma luz nos comentários.

Para eu notificar o usuário, basta eu colocar o atributo `role` com o valor `alert` e o atributo `aria-live` com o valor `assertive` em meu loading.

Assim o leitor de tela já avisa o usuário.